# Конфигурация Spring Boot с использованием gradle

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, развертывание

Есть приложение, написанное на Spring Boot. Для сборки используется gradle.

Проблема заключается в том, что мне нужны две отдельные конфигурации проекта для локального запуска и для деплоя.

**Для локального** запуска мне нужно:

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

и

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
```

в `build.gradle`.

А **для деплоя** мне нужно:

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

и

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
```

в `build.gradle`

Ну и плюс к этому ещё для некоторых бинов хотелось бы при инициализации иметь возможность что-то изменить в зависимости от конфигурации.

Сейчас я при сборке war всё это меняю руками, но это же глупость какая-то, есть же система сборки, пусть она сама всё делает =)

Comment: для конфигурации бинов можно использовать https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: @MikhailVaysman , спасибо за наводку, часть задачи решена